# obtain demographic data with google analytics api

Tags: analytics, google-analytics-api

im trying to obtain some demographic data from the google analytics api, my intention is to integrate this on a cms  to generate reports, etc... is this possible?

if it is, is there someone who knows a tutorial or something? i have used the examples provided and i get some sessions that have been in the last 7 day period. But nothing besides that. If that is not possible, what kind of things i can obtain with this api?

here is what i have tried:

```
function getResults(&$analytics, $profileId) {
  return $analytics->data_ga->get(
      'ga:' . $profileId,
      '7daysAgo',
      'today',
      'ga:sessions');
}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain everything that's listed in the [Dimensions and Metrics Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets). This includes ga:userAgeBracket and ga:userGender for demographic information.

To include additional metrics (numerical data) you put it as a parameter where you now have ga:sessions (separate multiple metrics with a comma). You need at least one metric for a query to work.

To add dimensions (i.e. categorical data) you need to pass an options array to your query that has a key/value pair for dimensions. This may also include additional options like filters or sort options, [see the example here.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide#build-a-core-reporting-api-query).

```
$optParams = array(
      'dimensions' => 'ga:userAgeBracket,ga:userGender'
);

return $analytics->data_ga->get(
      'ga:' . $profileId,
      '7daysAgo',
      'today',
      'ga:sessions',
      $optParams
);
```

This for version 3 of the API. If you are just getting started an have no legacy code to maintain you [might as well start with there current version (v4)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/#quick_start_guides).

Comment: Can you please tell me how do I get user's email address and contact details? Is there any option in google analytics reports api v4?

Comment: @Amit, no, you are not even allowed to store personal identifiable information within Google Analytics. That would be a violation of Google's TOS, and in some legislations (e.g. Europe) a breach of applicable law.

Comment: thanks for letting me know. Could you please tell me how do I retrieve the user's page visits, staying one the page etc. information.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to get age and gender informations from analytics, you should Enable Demographics and Interests reports on your GA account.
doc : https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2819948

Comment: thanks for the reply. Am I need to have admin access to make the changes? Or more issue, I am uploading my project via GCConsole and it is uploaded into AppEngine by default. Is this correct approach?