# What type of metric use in Core Reporting API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api

I want to get the common informtion about user browser statistics.

For this I use the following JS object:

```
 gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
        'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
        'start-date': '7daysAgo',
        'end-date': 'today',
        'metrics' : '',
        'dimensions' : 'ga:browser'
      })
```

What type of metrics I should set to get common statisti about users browsers?

Comment: Browsers are not a metric (metrics are numeric - numbers, percentages and currencies). Browsers are a dimenson (ga:dimension). To see how to pass in dimensons to a query look here (PHP, but the principle is the same): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37488470/obtain-demographic-data-with-google-analytics-api

Comment: There is a typo in the comment, of course the name for the "browsers" dimension is ga:browsers. Sorry about that.